# Optimizing a mesh for voxel cube landscapes

Tags: 3d-meshes, optimization, voxels

Playing around with creating minecraftish/lego world landscapes in Unity 3D (procedurally generated voxel landscapes with cubes), I'm finding that the meshes created for these landscapes take up a LOT of memory. The mesh currently only consists of vertices for visible sides of a cube. Memory usage for a complex terrain may take 6 or 7 hundred megs.

These meshes could be optimized, but I'm struggling to find a decent algorithm to do this.

The algorithm has to take into account that you don't want to "merge" blocks that are of different terrain types. I guess a really simple start might be to just process all blocks along one axis, and do extra sweeps for the other two axis.

I need to keep the mesh shape, that is no merging of vertices to the point that empty or solid space is changed. The reason is, there may be creatures/etc that still need to navigate around the mesh. So I can't just create a really low detail, distorted mesh.

Any thoughts/suggestions/tips on this?

Comment: Why are you storing vertices for a known size cube? Do it algorithmically; or use a shared vertex buffer.

Comment: Why polygonal mesh? [Voxel can be rendered quite efficiently just like they are](http://advsys.net/ken/voxlap.htm). For one voxel cube You need 3 floats (x,y,z), for 1 box You need around 8*3 floats (8 vertices), and that in case You have implicit edges and polygons. Maybe Unity is not the tool for this voxel problem.

Answer (score 5):

My question is:

Why would you need the mesh itself to do creature movement?

Can't you do the pathing calculation on a 3d matrix of id's?

I think Minecraft uses a 3d matrix with 4 bits pr block. It also only simulates creatures a certain radius around the player.

You could store your chunks in a oc-tree structure, where each chunk is compressed.

If you keep the compressed data in RAM you can decompress the data quite quickly when needed.

[image]

Comment: I was relying on having the mesh for built in collision detection with Unity, but there's nothing to stop me from just testing collision/pathing against a custom data structure. However, I still need to create a visible mesh for displaying the terrain, and this is what I need to optimize.

Comment: One other point...as you can see by the screenshot...there's not a whole lot of this terrain that is flat. The meshes are generally rough surfaces of cubes, but I think there is some room for optimizing the mesh faces/vertices. It seems like an octree would be best for data which has a lot of similiar blocks of data, instead of of "jaggy" data. Or is this not correct?

Comment: @Gatorfrog: Remember, empty space is a data too. if it's jaggy then sure, there will be lots of bits signalling its empty. The octree is just there for you to figure out which chunks you should decompress before you render them. Empty space will just be a bunch of zeroes. My dayjob involves working with a very sophisticated voxel rendering library. My next post will describe what they do.

Comment: The library i work with does the following:
Creates chunks of data and store them in a flat file database. Each chunk has an id. Each cube consists of many chunks. For each chunk there are created a certain number of levels of detail. Where the highest level of detail has 100% of the voxels, the second highest has 25% of all the voxels and then divide by 4 all for each subsequent level. Chunks that are close to you can be visualized using the highest level of detail.

Comment: all data is shipped in a compressed form from the RAM to the VRAM where it is inflated by GPGPU compression algorithms running in CUDA. This saves a lot of memory bandwith. So: CHeck where the player is and get high level of detail chunks there, the things furthest away can easily be visualized using one of the lower LODs.

Comment: The dudes who wrote this library are some of the best graphics programmers in the world and have been programming computer graphics for almost 20 years.

Comment: So, for chunks that are starting to be slightly foggy because they are past a certain distance, as in my screenshots, it doesn't matter if creatures exactly appear to be following the terrain. You are saying I should simply draw a less detailed mesh for these chunks, and generate a more detailed one as the chunks get closer? Would this be a problem if I decided not to have fog at all, as chunks further away would look odd?

Comment: What I am talking about is mostly about the data-structure you're going to save the data in. Anyway, since a chunk with the second highest lod will have 25% of the cubes of the highest lvel you can get away with rendring a lot less cubes. Let's call the highest level of detail LOD0 and the second highest LOD1, LOD2 and so on.

Comment: LOD1 will be the same as LOD0 only that 4 and 4 cubes will "melt" together and appear as one. At a distance, this is hardly noticable. I will say that i'm not sure how rendering performance will be in a polygonal world. Remember, I'm working with a voxel rendering libary. I can try to create a drawing for you.

Comment: I believe I see what you mean, Nailer. Honestly...the data structure is taking up a very small portion of memory, compared to the mesh data. a 512x512x128 world of blocks, or 33 million+ blocks, takes up about 33 megs. The meshes take up a lot more, I suppose because they contain information on vertex colors, uvs, vertices, etc. I guess I was hoping that there was an algorithm out there that progressively and quickly could "merge" verticies for similar blocks. Maybe I'll have to come up with something that will do eh? :)

Comment: Posted a pic. As you see a cube of 4x4x4(64) will be down to 2x2x2(8) at medium distance and 1 at long distance. Notice how colors are averaged between the chunks.

Comment: Oh and btw, have you tried just keeping 8 vertices in memory then transforming that one cube around instead of saving baggillions of vertices in the VRAM? I guess that might be slower, i'm not entirely sure.

Comment: I'm not sure that is something I can do with Unity, I can ask around  their community though. However, it might be a bit slow, as the cpu would be doing a lot more work as opposed to the gfx card.

Comment: *DX11 has hardware geometry instancing.
*Matrix computations could be done on the GPU
*Shaders could fake the furthest away boxes. Just a few suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

How about using an octree to store the terrain?

E.g. air = no node, all other terrain types would have a node with the terrain type.

When inserting/removing nodes, you could check if all eight children of each node on the modified tree path have the same terain type and merge them if needed.
That way, big blocks of the same material would only take up one node.

Answer (score 0):

Are you only creating the cubes for parts of the geometry the player can see?  That would be my first step.  Depending on the size of your terrain you don't have to have the entirety of the world loaded/drawing/visible/whatever.

Comment: I'm only creating the mesh for sides of cubes that have empty air next to them. As far as not drawing meshes that the player can't see...I thought about excluding any chunks that didn't have any visible blocks, such as underground caves or holes that led into the ground at an angle. I would definitely not be able to rely on my meshes for collision/pathing at that point, though.